# What is best for defining a title for a company page within a directory?

Tags: seo

What is best for defining a title for a company page within a directory?
Is it better to use `h1` or `href`?

Comment: Why not both? They are not exclusive

Answer (score 1):

I'd use h1, have a banner with a dummy clear image on top of the logo that is wrapped in an href back to the home page.